# Compare one column in a dataframe to two columns of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I need to know if the values of the first dataframe are between two values (min and max values) in the second dataframe.

I did something similar before with two other data frames, I used a nested `loop` and `between {dplyr}`. However, the other dataset only had three variables and I could make it work with 8 `if` statements. This is where I get stuck, dataframe1 has 62 variables and 477 observations and dataframe2 has 124 variables and 50 observations (min values and max values). Below I have an example of the two dataframes and the result I am looking for.

So I am looking for a solution where I don’t have to write around a thousand `if else` statements. I hope someone can help or if this is even possible.

The example of how the data looks, I can still change the dataframes, however this is the point where I am at.

```
Df1
   id type data1 data2 data3
1   1   ab     0     0     0
2   2   cd     0     0     0
3   3   dd     0    10     5
4   4   ed     0     0     0
5   5   kd     0     0    15
6   6   xd     0     5     0
7   7   ab     0     0     0
8   8   cd     0     0     0
9   9   dd     0    10    10
10 10   ed     0     0     0
11 11   kd     0     0    12
12 12   xd     0    12     0
13 13   ab     0     0     0
14 14   cd     0     0     0
15 15   dd     0     5    15
16 16   ed     0     0     0
17 17   kd     0     0    15
18 18   xd     0     7     0
19 19   ab     0     0     0
20 20   cd     0     0     0
21 21   dd     0    18    10
22 22   ed     0     0     0
23 23   kd     0     0     5
```

I usually match the "type" with each other and then match if the data is between the lower and upper boundary.

```
Df2
  type data1 data1max data2 data2max data3 data3max
1   ab    NA       NA    NA       NA    NA       NA
2   dd    NA       NA     5       20    10      100
3   xd    NA       NA     1       30    NA       NA
4   ed    NA       NA    NA       NA    NA       NA
5   cd    NA       NA    NA       NA    NA       NA
6   kd    NA       NA    NA       NA     5       20
```

And resulting in a count when the observed data matches the qualifying data.

```
Df3
   id type qualifyingfields
1   1   ab                0
2   2   cd                0
3   3   dd                1
4   4   ed                0
5   5   kd                1
6   6   xd                1
7   7   ab                0
8   8   cd                0
9   9   dd                2
10 10   ed                0
11 11   kd                1
12 12   xd                1
13 13   ab                0
14 14   cd                0
15 15   dd                2
16 16   ed                0
17 17   kd                1
18 18   xd                1
19 19   ab                0
20 20   cd                0
21 21   dd                1
22 22   ed                0
23 23   kd                1
```

Comment: @sorlac The first question, duplicate type in df1? In my real dataset, on the research site a type can occur more than once and the measured values can be different for the same type over and area. I tried to mimic this in df1 when I created it as an example. 
The second question, the relationship between the two? Df1 is measured data, df2 contains the range of desired values for the different types that can occur in df1. 
Final question, I didn’t do any processing for df3, df3 would be the desired output as I use the count to determine the quality of the specific ‘id’ and ‘type’ combination

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a more general solution that applies to  data regardless of how many `data[n]` columns are

```r
library('dplyr')
library('tidyr')

# Make dataframes tidy
Df1_tidy <- Df1 %>%   
    gather(key='data_name', value='value', -(id:type))

Df2_tidy <- Df2 %>%
    gather(key='data_name', value='value', -type) %>%
    mutate(limit=ifelse(grepl('max', data_name), 'Max', 'Min'),
           data_name=gsub('max', '', data_name)) %>% 
    spread(limit, value) 

# Count qualifying fields
Df3 <- full_join(Df1_tidy, Df2_tidy) %>%
    group_by(id, type) %>%
    summarise(qualifyingfields = sum(value >= Min & value <= Max, na.rm=T)) %>%
    ungroup()

Df3
# # A tibble: 23 x 3
#       id type  qualifyingfields
#    <int> <chr>            <int>
#  1     1 ab                   0
#  2     2 cd                   0
#  3     3 dd                   1
#  4     4 ed                   0
#  5     5 kd                   1
#  6     6 xd                   1
#  7     7 ab                   0
#  8     8 cd                   0
#  9     9 dd                   2
# 10    10 ed                   0
# # ... with 13 more rows
```

**Get data (copied from @M-- response):**

```r
df1 <- read.table(text="   id type data1 data2 data3
1   1   ab     0     0     0
2   2   cd     0     0     0
3   3   dd     0    10     5
4   4   ed     0     0     0
5   5   kd     0     0    15
6   6   xd     0     5     0
7   7   ab     0     0     0
8   8   cd     0     0     0
9   9   dd     0    10    10
10 10   ed     0     0     0
11 11   kd     0     0    12
12 12   xd     0    12     0
13 13   ab     0     0     0
14 14   cd     0     0     0
15 15   dd     0     5    15
16 16   ed     0     0     0
17 17   kd     0     0    15
18 18   xd     0     7     0
19 19   ab     0     0     0
20 20   cd     0     0     0
21 21   dd     0    18    10
22 22   ed     0     0     0
23 23   kd     0     0     5", 
header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 <- read.table(text="  type data1 data1max data2 data2max data3 data3max
1   ab    NA       NA    NA       NA    NA       NA
2   dd    NA       NA     5       20    10      100
3   xd    NA       NA     1       30    NA       NA
4   ed    NA       NA    NA       NA    NA       NA
5   cd    NA       NA    NA       NA    NA       NA
6   kd    NA       NA    NA       NA     5       20", 
header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings = "NA")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfect. Though, in my data it also generates 50 rows with 'type = NA', for every type in df2.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  right_join(., df2, by = "type", suffix = c("val", "min")) %>% 
  group_by(type, id) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, type), names_to = "data", values_to = "value") %>% 
  separate(col = data, into = c("data", "var"), sep = "(?<=\\d)") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = value) %>% 
  group_by(id, type, data) %>% 
  mutate(qualifyingfields = sum(between(val, min, max), na.rm = T)) %>% 
  group_by(id, type) %>% 
  summarise(qualifyingfields = sum(qualifyingfields))

#> # A tibble: 23 x 3
#> # Groups:   type, id [23]
#>       id type  qualifyingfields
#>    <int> <chr>            <int>
#>  1     1 ab                   0
#>  2     2 cd                   0
#>  3     3 dd                   1
#>  4     4 ed                   0
#>  5     5 kd                   1
#>  6     6 xd                   1
#>  7     7 ab                   0
#>  8     8 cd                   0
#>  9     9 dd                   2
#> 10    10 ed                   0
#> # ... with 13 more rows
```

***Data:***

```
df1 <- read.table(text="   id type data1 data2 data3
1   1   ab     0     0     0
2   2   cd     0     0     0
3   3   dd     0    10     5
4   4   ed     0     0     0
5   5   kd     0     0    15
6   6   xd     0     5     0
7   7   ab     0     0     0
8   8   cd     0     0     0
9   9   dd     0    10    10
10 10   ed     0     0     0
11 11   kd     0     0    12
12 12   xd     0    12     0
13 13   ab     0     0     0
14 14   cd     0     0     0
15 15   dd     0     5    15
16 16   ed     0     0     0
17 17   kd     0     0    15
18 18   xd     0     7     0
19 19   ab     0     0     0
20 20   cd     0     0     0
21 21   dd     0    18    10
22 22   ed     0     0     0
23 23   kd     0     0     5", 
header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df2 <- read.table(text="  type data1 data1max data2 data2max data3 data3max
1   ab    NA       NA    NA       NA    NA       NA
2   dd    NA       NA     5       20    10      100
3   xd    NA       NA     1       30    NA       NA
4   ed    NA       NA    NA       NA    NA       NA
5   cd    NA       NA    NA       NA    NA       NA
6   kd    NA       NA    NA       NA     5       20", 
header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings = "NA")
```